# get json object like C# class from input name by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i wrote a function (JQuery) that gather all inputs values and make a JSON Object by input's id and its value. the ids are generated bu MVC.
like this

```
   {
    "prop1":"1"
    "class1_prop2":"2"
    "class1_prop3":"3"
   }
```

I want to convert this class to its related C# class. I mean I want to have a property with name class1 that has to property with names prop2 and prop3. i need to do like modelbinder in javascript and jquery level.

what can i do?
thanks.

Comment: You can create `dictionary<string, string>` in c#, or custom class with indexer and dictionary to store values.

Comment: As far as i know you can't add fields to c# classes at runtime, the only way to this would be if you know exacly the datastructure

Comment: i need to deserialize data to model class. and dictionary<string, string> cant help me. i know i cant add class at runtime in C# but jquery can do this, so i use this and serialize it to the server for mapping to the model that defined before. thanks

Comment: What advantage you see in class (skiping methods) ?

Comment: i have a class in c# and some inputs in view corresponding to the class. i cant use unobtrusive mode to pass the data to the controller. so i get data by jquery. but the inner classes are named by "_" and i need to convert them to classes that serializer can do its job.

Comment: you mentioned c#, can you pull in web api?  then you can create a custom serializer.  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/09/using-an-alternate-json-serializer-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: _i use this and serialize it to the server for mapping to the model that defined before_ - if you already have such a model defined, why don't you use that model itself as action parameter type?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
// serialize Json.NET
// http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

public class ClassTop
{
    public string prop1{ get; set; }
    public Class1 prop { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}

Class1 prop = new Class1()
prop.prop2 = "2";
prop.prop3 = "3";

ClassTop input = new ClassTop();
input.prop1 = "1";
input.prop = prop;

// serialize
string outputjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

// deserialize
ClassTop item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassTop>(outputjson);
```